# AWS Lambda Code Unable to Import Depdendencies from S3 -- Runtime.ImportModuleError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, dependencies

I'm trying to deploy a Python lambda function with external dependencies, but I'm hitting an error because it doesn't see my external dependencies. `"Unable to import module 'metrics': No module named 'github'"`

Here's my deploy script. My python script with the lambda_handler() is `metrics.py`.

```
mkdir lambda_code

# populate lambda_code directory with python libraries
pip3 install --quiet -r requirements.txt --target lambda_code/

# compress the lambda_code directory and add metrics.py to the zip
zip -qq -r9 lambda_code.zip lambda_code/

zip -qq -g lambda_code.zip metrics.py

aws s3 cp lambda_code.zip s3://$BUCKET/lambda_code.zip

aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $FUNCTION_NAME --s3-bucket $BUCKET --s3-key lambda_code.zip
```

Here's the tree of my upacked lamdba_code.zip **This is where things aren't working.** It doesn't make sense to me why the lambda can't see the github module. I've also tried putting `metrics.py` directly in the lambda_code directory, but still nothing.

```
.
├── lambda_code
│   ├── Deprecated-1.2.5.dist-info
│   ├── PyGithub-1.43.7.dist-info
│   ├── PyJWT-1.7.1.dist-info
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── bin
│   ├── certifi
│   ├── certifi-2019.3.9.dist-info
│   ├── chardet
│   ├── chardet-3.0.4.dist-info
│   ├── cycler-0.10.0.dist-info
│   ├── cycler.py
│   ├── dateutil
│   ├── deprecated
│   ├── easy_install.py
│   ├── github
│   ├── idna
│   ├── idna-2.8.dist-info
│   ├── jwt
│   ├── kiwisolver-1.1.0.dist-info
│   ├── kiwisolver.cpython-37m-darwin.so
│   ├── matplotlib
│   ├── matplotlib-3.0.3-py3.7-nspkg.pth
│   ├── matplotlib-3.0.3.dist-info
│   ├── mpl_toolkits
│   ├── numpy
│   ├── numpy-1.16.3.dist-info
│   ├── pandas
│   ├── pandas-0.24.2.dist-info
│   ├── pkg_resources
│   ├── pylab.py
│   ├── pyparsing-2.4.0.dist-info
│   ├── pyparsing.py
│   ├── python_dateutil-2.8.0.dist-info
│   ├── pytz
│   ├── pytz-2019.1.dist-info
│   ├── requests
│   ├── requests-2.21.0.dist-info
│   ├── setuptools
│   ├── setuptools-41.0.1.dist-info
│   ├── six-1.12.0.dist-info
│   ├── six.py
│   ├── urllib3
│   ├── urllib3-1.24.3.dist-info
│   ├── wrapt
│   └── wrapt-1.11.1.dist-info
└── metrics.py
```

Finally, here's the beginning of the lambda code. The error occurs when trying to import github.

```
"""Obtains total number of releases on Github.com and creates data 
visualizations"""

import datetime
import io
import os
import sys

from base64 import b64decode
from github import Github
import boto3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

ENCRYPTED = os.environ['github_credentials']
DECRYPTED = 
boto3.client('kms').decrypt(CiphertextBlob=b64decode(ENCRYPTED)) . 
['Plaintext']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
```

Comment: Are files inside `lambda_code` in the zip too? They should be in the root directory of the zip, otherwise you need to import `lambda_code.github`.

Comment: Yeah, `lambda_code` is the unpacked version of `lambda_code.zip`. I'm going to try modifying the import statement however

Comment: This did not solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: You might be missing `__init__.py` file. Best to just move all files to the root folder. It's the more correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to have your `metrics.py` and the sub folders of `lambda_code` into a single folder, or you need to import the modules like, `lambda_code.pytz` for each module that is zipped.

If you follow your current directory structure, `lambda_code` becomes a module and all other modules can be referred only using `lambda_code.` because, folders inside `lambda_code` becomes sub modules of `lambda_code`. I would suggest you to copy sub folders of `lambda_code` to root directory, i.e. the directory which your `metrics.py` resides. Then delete the `lambda_code` folder and zip and upload. This way, you might not need to edit your code.